# Error: Cannot insert the value NULL into column

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, ado.net

I have a gridview tied to a sqldatasource. Trying to run the update stored proc.

I keep getting this error...

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'MyFKId', table 'dbo.MyTable'; 
column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been 
terminated.
```

I know the answer seems obvious, that I am trying to insert a null into a column that doesn't allow it. The problem is that I know I am putting a value into 'MyFKId'. In my code I set a breakpoint and saw there was a value after this line ran...

```
dsMyDataSource.UpdateParameters.Item("MyFKId").DefaultValue = SomeId
```

SomeId did indeed have a value. It was not null. What do you think could be wrong? The SQLDataSource is setup as follows...

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsMyDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="xxxxx"
    SelectCommand="xxxxx" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"  
    UpdateCommandType="Text"  
    UpdateCommand=" Execute s_MyStoredProc @MyFKId,...@UserId">
      <UpdateParameters>
             <asp:Parameter Name="MyFKId" Type="Int32" />
              ...
      </UpdateParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: You'll need to post the code in `s_MyStoredProc` as well to get a reasonable answer.

Comment: When I set the breakpoint I do see the defaultvalue gets a value from the SomeId variable. There's no code that adjusts it after that. Where else should I check?

Comment: Are you sure that your stored proc is working correctly?

Comment: The parameter is whatever SQL Server sees, not what you _think_ SQL Server should see. Clearly, there's a difference between the two.

Comment: I think you have to show the stored procedure. Make sure the parameter `MyFKId` is what you expect in the stored procedure.

Comment: Exception message says **`INSERT fails`**. Maybe you need to set the `InsertParameters` property.

Comment: He calls a stored procedure.

Comment: The problem was a reference to an old, but very similar sqldatasource. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `EXECUTE` to call your stored procedure. Use `InsertCommand`

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsMyDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="xxxxx"
    InsertCommand="s_MyStoredProc" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure">
      <InsertParameters>
             <asp:Parameter Name="MyFKId" Type="Int32" />
              ...
      </InsertParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And use InsertParameters to set the parameter.

```
dsMyDataSource.InsertParameters("MyFKId").DefaultValue = SomeId
```

Can not try it but hope that will solve it for you.

Comment: The stored proc actually does INSERTS and UPDATES, depending on certain variables and logic. But technically, in this context, it's working as an Update query/command.

Comment: The reason why you should use InsertCommand is not about what your stored procedure really does, its for properly assigning values to the parameters. InsertCommand makes sure it doesn't expect results from that query. Theres simply no UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure" so you have to use InsertCommand for executing the stored procedure. It should work for any stored procedure which doesn't return query results. Just try my proposal.